# How to exclude NaNs in summation R

Tags: r

I have got a problem. When I want to sum vectors there is some NaNs, because denominator is sometimes zero. How can I prevent it?
Here is code:

```
x = sample(c(1:20), 25, replace = T)
y = sample(c(1:20), 25, replace = T)
i = 1
n = length(x)-1
result = c()
for(i in 1:n){
 result[i]=sum(sin(x[i+1]/(y[i+1]-y[i])), na.rm = TRUE)
}
sum(result)
```

Comment: Just add `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: It is in sum() function I just wondering, can I pick out samples to fit with denominator

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, samples of what and does "to fit" mean?

Comment: Can I add condition (anywhere) to draw vectors values where y[i+1]-y[i] =/= 0.?

Comment: quick comment; the sum within the loop is not needed as it is summing a vector of length one at each iteration. You can vectorise this using `sum(sin(x[-1] / diff(y)), na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Using @user20650's suggestion, `d <-  diff(y); result <- sin(x[-1][d != 0]/d[d != 0])`. No loops, no `NaN`, same `sum(result)`.